# Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx instance set up with a reverse proxy like so:

```
    server {
     listen 80;
     server_name sitep-rate00.sv.walmartlabs.com;
     location / {
     proxy_pass http://www.example.com;
    }
  }
```

How can I set the css style sheet to a specific version, for example something like:

```
Substitute 's|styles/sheets.1.1.1(.*)\.css"|styles/sheets.1.1.33.css"|i'
```

Comment: before or after the proxy pass? on which server does the css live on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to proxy pass it too you can try a rewrite before the proxy pass

```
location / {
  rewrite /styles/sheets.1.1.1(.*)\.css /styles/sheets.1.1.33.css last;
  proxy_pass example.com;
}
```